# NSClient++ Using Default Certificate Instead of Mine

Tags: ssl, nagios, nrpe

I am trying to set up secure communication between my Nagios server (check_nrpe) and a Windows host running NSClient with NRPE daemon enabled.
I have defined the cert directives in nsclient.ini correctly, I believe, but when I start NSClient++, it creates a new 'certificate.pem' and places it in the security directory.
Could anyone help me understand why NSClient is ignoring the certs I provided it and creating its own?

Here is nsclient.ini:

```
[/settings/default]

; Undocumented key
password = nagiospass1

; Undocumented key
allowed hosts = xxx,xxx

use ssl = 1

verify mode = peer-cert
allowed ciphers = ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH
ca = C:\Program Files\NSClient++\security\ca_cert.pem
certificate = C:\Program Files\NSClient++\security\client_cert.pem
certificate key = C:\Program Files\NSClient++\security\client_key.pem

[/settings/NRPE/server]
allow arguments = 1
allow nasty characters = true
timeout = 45

verify mode = peer-cert
use ssl = 1
ssl_client_certs = 2
allowed ciphers = ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH
certificate = C:\Program Files\NSClient++\security\client_cert.pem
certificate key = C:\Program Files\NSClient++\security\client_key.pem
ca = C:\Program Files\NSClient++\security\ca_cert.pem
dh=
```